# Resizeable ListeningExecutorService

Tags: java, guava, executorservice

I've gotten into the habit of wrapping `ExecutorService`s in a `listeningDecorator` to make a `ListeningExecutorService`. I understand this is the Guava team's recommendation, and it seems to always be worthwhile.

I am running into an issue here, however. My executors are invariable based on a standard `ThreadPoolExecutor`, and I would like to give control of that thread pool size to my application (and, particularly, to expose it to administrators supporting the application). With an undecorated `ThreadPoolExecutor`, the methods needed to do this are exposed, but the wrapper is hiding the delegate from me.

So, what would I need to do to get back to the api exposed by the `ThreadPoolExecutor` without giving up the `listeningDecorator`?

A couple of ideas I had were:

1. Make a new `ListeningDecorator` that exposes the delegate
2. Keep a reference to the delegate as well as to the decorated `Executor`
3. Only keep a reference to the `ThreadPoolExecutor`, and wrap it only when the `ExecutorService` as it is requested
4. Reflect my way in to the delegate and manipulate the thread pool size from there

Comment: Agreed. Personally, I've always found it more extensible and maintainable to extend/override an existing design to add functionality than to try and play with global references or what have you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guava team member here.

I would write a new `ListeningThreadPoolExecutor` class that's basically a `ListeningDecorator` variant wrapping a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but instead of exposing the delegate itself, I'd expose `setCorePoolSize(int size)` methods from the `ListeningThreadPoolExecutor` that forwarded to the delegate `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

That approach exposes even fewer internal details than option 1, but failing that, I'd fall back to option 1 as you've described it.

Comment: Hmm, so apparently I can't actually implement my own `ListeningExecutorService` because I'm on Java 5 and the type paramaters in that interface are done in a way that is not Java 5 friendly

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure if you have any options at all.  Option 3 probably comes the closest, but...there's not going to be a nice solution.  (That said, I'm surprised about your problems with Java 5, and I'd like to hear more detail...and you _are_ aware that Guava is moving to Java 6 with the upcoming release?)

Comment: It looks like the third option will actually be alright for me, because even if there are multiple instances of the decorator, the bulk of it is in the the ThreadPoolExecutor, which will have a single instance--and more importantly a single backing queue.

Comment: Regarding the Java 5/6 issue--I'll either post that as a separate question or move to guava-discuss

Comment: @LouisWasserman The `ExecutorService` method signatures for `invokeAll/Any` change between Java 5 and 6 in a very incompatible way [(see Ray's other question)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237259/implementing-listeningexecutorservice-in-java-5).

Comment: Well I was able to get this to work after all, thanks to thutheality's suggestion in [my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237259/implementing-listeningexecutorservice-in-java-5#comment13156837_10237259)