# Implementing ListeningExecutorService in Java 5

Tags: java, guava, type-erasure, type-parameter

In Java 5, the `ExecutorService` interface declares the method:

```
<T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(Collection<Callable<T>> tasks)
    throws InterruptedException;
```

whereas Guava 11.0.2, written in Java 6 but supposedly compatible with Java 5, overrides it in `ListeningExecutorService` as:

```
 <T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)
     throws InterruptedException;
```

If I want to implement my own `ListeningExecutorService`, I would need to implement both of these methods, but I am also not able to have two methods the same erasure, so it's a bit of a Catch 22.

Is there any way around this problem? More specifically, is there any way to implement a `ListeningExecutorService` in Java 5?

As a side note to any Guava folks--is it actually necessary for Guava to re-declare this method since it's already inherited from `ExecutorService`?

Comment: I think you have to pick what you're writing for -- Java 5 or 6. It looks like you can't implement an `ExecutorService` that is compatible with both.

Comment: In this application, there is no question--I am writing for Java 5. But I am using a library that was written in Java 6. When compiled, I have no problem using Guava (pre version 12), as the type erasures line up. It's only when I'm trying to implement this public interface that I get the conflict.

Comment: It's necessary for Guava to redeclare this method if we want to add any documentation -- which we really kind of do.  =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that we made this work was to override the JDK's ExecutorService interface in our bootclasspath.  You could do something similar during your project's compilation.  The easiest way to see our setup is probably [the change that removed it for release 12](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/detail?r=81c09f3e5cd27a246cae58247825aa96af94b99d&name=release12) (since that release will require JDK6).

Answer (score 4):

The original method signature has been reported as a bug and fixed for JDK 6:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6267833

To quote the resolution message:

> - is binary compatible.

- is source compatible for *users* of an ExecutorService
- requires minor source code changes for the small set of developers
  who have implemented ExecutorService without inheriting the
  default implementations in AbstractExecutorService.  The set of
  affected developers are developers creating sophisticated
  thread pool applications, putting them into the
  "concurrency rocket scientist" category.  They will generally
  appreciate this change.  The possible compiler error is trivial
  to fix in the source code.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't help the OP if he's stuck with Java 5.  =/

Comment: Louis is right but I +1'd because that's great background info

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of implementing both interfaces, scary as it is, is

```
List invokeAll(Collection tasks)
```

drop the generic types, document why you are doing it, and be very careful.

Comment: I agree that this ought to work, but when I tried it, the compiler I was using produced an internal error.  YMMV, but you may be setting yourself up for trouble down the line.  (Then again, maybe down the line you'll be using JDK6.)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, Chris. In several of my projects, I'm on JDK 6, but this one I am stuck on 5... out of my hands.

Comment: @thrutheality, it makes my cry to have to use a raw type, but it does work. Thanks for the suggestion.